# Is it possible to put an encrypted message inside another message in Python using AES?

Tags: python, json, encryption, aes, communication

I have to implement the following communication scheme between Alice and Bob in Python.

[image]

I happen to be having some problems in step 5, as I have to concatenate one encrypted message inside another, and I don't think I'm doing it right. As a consequence, Bob produces console errors when I run his code.

Specifically, the error that occurs is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/javimp2003/Seguridad de la Información/Wuolah/ExamenPracEvaluable/b.py", line 48, in 
> mesIntDescifrado = json.loads(internoDescifrado)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/**init**.py", line 341, in loads
> s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: invalid start byte

In order for you to understand the origin of the error, I am going to copy the key parts of the 3 codes.

**TTP code (the one that produces the session key KAB):**

```
ts = datetime.timestamp(dt) # entiendo que en dt esta la hora actual de mi sistema en float
claveSesion = aes.crear_AESKey()

messageParaA = []
messageParaA.append(str(ts))
messageParaA.append(claveSesion.hex())
jStr = json.dumps(messageParaA)

cuatro_aes_cifrado, nonceFirst = aes.iniciarAES_CTR_cifrado(dosKBT)
cuatroCifrado = aes.cifrarAES_CTR(cuatro_aes_cifrado,jStr.encode("utf-8"))

#print(f"RESTOENC: {cuatroCifrado}")

messageParaA.append(cuatroCifrado.hex())
jStrAux = json.dumps(messageParaA)
cuatro_aes_cifrado_aux, nonceSecond = aes.iniciarAES_CTR_cifrado(unoKAT)
cuatroCifradoTotal = aes.cifrarAES_CTR(cuatro_aes_cifrado_aux,jStrAux.encode("utf-8"))

socketConA.enviar(nonceFirst) #interno
socketConA.enviar(nonceSecond) #exterior
socketConA.enviar(cuatroCifradoTotal)
```

**Alice code**

```
nonceCifradoInterno = socketConTTP.recibir()
nonceCifrado = socketConTTP.recibir()
cuatroCifrado = socketConTTP.recibir()

aes_descifrar = aes.iniciarAES_CTR_descifrado(keyConTTP,nonceCifrado)
cuatroDescifrado = aes.descifrarAES_CTR(aes_descifrar,cuatroCifrado)
messageDescifrado = json.loads(cuatroDescifrado)

ts, claveSesion, elResto = messageDescifrado
claveSesion = bytearray.fromhex(claveSesion) # ya esta en bytes para poder usarla como clave

socketConTTP.cerrar()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

socketConversacion = socket.SOCKET_SIMPLE_TCP('127.0.0.1',5555)
socketConversacion.conectar()

messageCinco = []
messageCinco.append("Alice")
messageCinco.append(ts)
jStrCinco = json.dumps(messageCinco)

aes_cif, nonceCinco = aes.iniciarAES_CTR_cifrado(claveSesion)
cincoCifrado = aes.cifrarAES_CTR(aes_cif,jStrCinco.encode("utf-8"))

socketConversacion.enviar(nonceCifradoInterno)
socketConversacion.enviar(elResto.encode("utf-8"))
socketConversacion.enviar(nonceCinco)
socketConversacion.enviar(cincoCifrado)
```

**Bob code**

```
socketConversacion = socket.SOCKET_SIMPLE_TCP('127.0.0.1',5555)
socketConversacion.escuchar()

nonceCifradoInterno = socketConversacion.recibir()
resto = socketConversacion.recibir()
nonceCinco = socketConversacion.recibir()
cincoCifrado = socketConversacion.recibir()

descifrado_interno = aes.iniciarAES_CTR_descifrado(keyConTTP,nonceCifradoInterno)
internoDescifrado = aes.descifrarAES_CTR(descifrado_interno,resto)
mesIntDescifrado = json.loads(internoDescifrado) #THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR IS PRODUCED

ts, claveSesion = mesIntDescifrado
claveSesion = bytearray.fromhex(claveSesion)

descifrarCinco = aes.iniciarAES_CTR_descifrado(claveSesion,nonceCinco)
cincoDescifrado = aes.descifrarAES_CTR(descifrarCinco,cincoCifrado)
mesCincoTotal = json.loads(cincoDescifrado)

name, time = mesCincoTotal
time = time.decode("utf-8")
if ts == time:
    print(f"Hola {name}. Te mando el ts incrementado...")
```

I tried to do some "decode("utf-8")" but this did not work. I even did "print" during the code as a debug to see what was the content of the messages that were being sent, but everything seemed fine.

Comment: Try to add `print(repr(...))` (or use a debugger) with interesting variables, especially `jStrCinco` in Alice and `cincoDescifrado` in Bob (before calling `loads`).

Comment: @MichaelButscher the output for jStrCinco is jStrCinco: ["Alice", "1697802480.837892"]
and cincoDescifrado cannot be shown because the error is produced before that line